# Properties of a matrix whose row vectors are dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

When a column vector in a matrix is a made up of "combination" of its other column vectors, it is said to be linearly dependant. Say...

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0\\ 
4 & 5 & -6\\ 
3 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
1\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
4\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
5\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-6\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}

$$

Otherwise, it is linearly independent. And being linearly dependent, it has the properties of being a singular matrix and therefore may have an infinite solutions or no solutions at all depending on the result matrix. Then being linearly independent, the matrix is more often a good matrix that can span the entire $R^{n}$ space and has a unique solution to its system of equations.

Then I just thinking what happens if a row vector in a matrix is made up of "combination" of its other row vectors? Say...

$$P=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 1\\ 
12 & 13 & 3\\ 
8 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
2\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 & 1
\end{bmatrix}+1\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
12 & 13 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Does a matrix have any special properties too if its **row vectors** are linearly independent and linearly dependent?

Thanks!

Comment: Dependence between the columns implies dependence between the rows, and vice-versa. Take a close look: the third row is, in fact, $1/17$ of the first row $+$ $3/17$ of the second row.

Comment: So I can safely say that the properties that apply to a matrix which is linearly independent for its column vectors is the same as another matrix that is linearly independent for its row vectors?

Comment: Essentially yes, since those qualities are equivalent -- you can't have one without another. =)

Comment: Any property that applies to _every_ square matrix with linearly independent columns also applies to every square matrix with linearly independent rows. (This is a tautology once you realise that these two classes of matrices are equal).

Comment: ahh... I see now... Thanks InterestedGuest and mac for the help! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The following are equivalent for a square matrix $A$:

1. $A$ is non-singular
2. the rows of $A$ are linearly independent
3. the columns of $A$ are linearly independent

Comment: More in general: any matrix has the same row and column "rank" (amount of linearly independent rows/columns). This is a fundamental property, and it's not obvious.

Comment: If the matrix is not a square matrix, what properties would differ?

Comment: @xEnOn: leonbloy's comment would still apply: The row rank and column rank are the same.