# Matrix Solutions

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $ A _ {3 \times3}$ matrix and suppose that

$$2a_1 + a_2 - 4a_3 = 0$$

How many solutions will the system $Ax = 0$ have?
Is $ A$ nonsingular?

(Underscore means subscript)

Comment: The way you've written this is unclear. Usually the entries of a matrix have two subscripts: for rows and columns.

Comment: This is how the book states it.

The variables represent columns.

Comment: Is there a picture? A three by three matrix has nine entries. You've listed only three. Are they the diagonal entries with the rest zero??

Comment: Columns: OK so now you have something to work with. Your relation means that the columns are linearly dependent.

Comment: See:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48032/properties-of-a-matrix-whose-row-vectors-are-dependent

Comment: So then I get the following:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2a11 \\
        2a21 \\
        2a31 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

+

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a12 \\
        a22 \\
        a32 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

-

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4a13 \\
        4a23 \\
        4a33 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

=

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I use 'x' here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how many solutions this matrix have i think infinitely many. However, of course, A is singular matrix because Ax=0 means that the determinant of A is 0, also columns are linearly dependent so again we can easily see that detA=0. Therefore the matrix A is not invertible which means that A is singular.

Comment: I'd like to write my answer as comment but i couldn't